# Is it possible to use Travis CI with Crashlytics for building and deploying an iOS App?

Tags: travis-ci, crashlytics

I see that integrating TestFlight and HockeyApp with Travis CI is supported, but I cannot find anything about using Crashlytics with Travis CI. Is it possible?

I thought maybe that the Crashlytics app was required on the server, but this page from the Crashlytics site suggests otherwise ... http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92533-does-crashlytics-support-ci-or-build-servers

I love Crashlytics' deployment, by HockeyApp looks like a viable alternative as they support iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashlytics supports iOS beta distribution on CI boxes. The dSYM upload process is the same (via Run Script Build Phase), but beta distribution is handled via command line calling the 'submit' binary.

Here's a KB article with all params: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/370383-beta-distribution-with-ios-build-servers